# Meteor forbidClientAccountCreation doesn't prevent oAuth account creation

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

```
Accounts.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: true
});
```

In lib, so both client and server.  Reset the database, then go to the client and try to login with accounts-google and useraccounts:core packages. Login is successful.

Expected behavior: Account not found, login denied.

Answer (score 0):

From the Meteor-Docs:

> **forbidClientAccountCreation Boolean**
>
> Calls to createUser from the client will be rejected. In addition, if
>   you are using accounts-ui, the "Create account" link will not be
>   available.

The Google-package will create the account via Meteor.loginWithGoogle, so that will work, even if you set `forbidClientAccountCreation` to true.

What you could do to disable account creation overall is to change the onCreateUser function to something like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('account_creation_disabled', 'Creation of new accounts is currently disabled');
});
```